# can I create custom tasks or validations before execute the "git push" command?

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

What I want is: at the moment of executing the command "git push", execute other some script to validate my code (Code review).

for example:
When run Git push -> run the MSBuild code analyzer (sonarqube scan), if there is an error does not allow "git push"

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for a [git hook](https://git-scm.com/book/gr/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks). In your case, a server-side pre-receive hook would do the trick.

A hook is a custom script that is run on certain events (e.g. the pre-receive hook is run before the server accepts a push). Depending on the script exit status, the operation (e.g. the push) is accepted or rejected.

Edit: [This](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-git-hooks-to-automate-development-and-deployment-tasks) might also help.